# The relation between $\inf_{R\in \mathsf{U}_n} \left\Vert A - BR\right\Vert^2_F$ and $\left\Vert AA^*-BB^*\right\Vert$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, nuclear-norm

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two arbitrary $m\times n$ matrices with $m>n$. Let $\mathsf{U}_n$ denote the set of $n\times n$ unitary matrices. I'd like find positive constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that 
$$
\begin{align*}
c_2\left\Vert AA^*-BB^*\right\Vert &\geq\inf_{R\in \mathsf{U}_n} \left\Vert A - BR\right\Vert^2_F \geq c_1\left\Vert AA^*-BB^*\right\Vert,
\end{align*}
$$ 
holds (and the inequalities are sharp enough). I'm more interested in the upped bound.

I have a partial answer that addresses some special cases. For example, if $n=1$ then I've shown that $c_2=\sqrt{2}$. Furthermore, if we assume that $A$ and $B$ have the same range, it's not difficult to find the appropriate $c_2$.

My conjecture is that $c_2 = \sqrt{2n}$, but I haven't been able to prove it. The infimum above is the standard *orthogonal Procrustes problem* and it is relatively straightforward to show that
$$
\begin{align*}
\inf_{R\in \mathsf{U}_n} \left\Vert A - BR\right\Vert^2_F &=\left\Vert A\right\Vert_F ^2 +\left\Vert B\right\Vert_F ^2 -2\left\Vert A^*B\right\Vert_*, 
\end{align*}
$$
where $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert_*$ denotes the *nuclear norm* (or the *Schatten 1-norm*).